# Setting datasource to android spinners as a Text_Field/Value_Field, similar to asp.net

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am trying to give my ArrayList as a datasource to a spinner, Where a property of CustomObject will be used as Display Field, and another property as a value field.

What we are currently doing is fill the display values in a string array, then use an ArrayAdapter to fill the spinner

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    m_Spnr.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrData);
            m_Spnr.setAdapter(adapter);`

Then I fill the value fields in another array, and use the selected index proprty to get the selected value.
How can this be achieved using an approach similar to that in ASP.net ( setting DisplayField and ValueField).

Thanks